# typescript import dependency with class

Tags: typescript

What is the best why to import this in typescript and get translate into js :

```
const randomBytes = require('react-native-randombytes').randomBytes;
```

I do this:

```
import * as randomBytes from 'react-native-randombyte';
```

It only give me:

```
const randomBytes = require('react-native-randombytes');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you’re looking for is:

```
import { randomBytes } from 'react-native-randombyte';
```

This essentially means you want to import only `randomBytes`, not the entire module. For more information, take a look at the TypeScript documentation here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-single-export-from-a-module